# How to display permutations generated using itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am using string.ascii_letters module to generate and store all ascii letters in a alphabets tuple, Then using this tuple to generate strings using the itertools library

I used a loop to iterate through all the words generated through the permutations function.

```py
alphabets=string.ascii_letters
for p in permutations(alphabets,1):
            print(p)
```

When i just print p

('a',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

I searched and came to know i had to use **print("".join(p))**
Why is that, since it is just a tuple generated, cant i just say since thats
how we iterate through a tuple

```
for p in ...
    print(p)
```

Comment: If `print(p)` printed `ab` for the tuple `('a', 'b')`, how would you ever print the tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing a tuple object, and `str(tuple_object)` will produce the `(`, `)` parentheses and the representations of each contained element. That's how the object was designed. Primitive data structures such as tuples, dictionaries and lists are not end-user friendly values and `print()` also can't just join the contents for you because generic data structures are not guaranteed to contain strings to join.

So you have to explicitly join the contents, because only you the developer know for certain that those tuples only ever contain strings.

You can also pass in the contents of the tuple to the `print()` function, and set the separator to the empty string:

```
print(*p, sep='')
```

All this has nothing to do with `itertools`, really. Any tuple would be treated this way, and `itertools.permutations()` is designed to give you tuples, not joined strings, because it too is generic and can't assume you are always passing in strings, and it can't assume that you as a developer wanted to always join strings.